# how to give values from xml file to datagridviewtextbox in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

lets say i got some xml file which looks like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1 id = "one">
    <Server>Server1</Server>
    <Database>Database1</Database>
  </Table1>
  <Table1 id = "two">
    <Server>Server2</Server>
    <Database>Database2</Database>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

what i want to do is that i want to read the values from this xml and put them in `datagridview`, in different columns. for ex: to show `Database1` and `Database2` in one column.
im using Xpath to get values from xml file, here is my code:

```
 private void xmlGetValues()
    {
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("C:\\XMLfile1.xml");
        XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

    XPathExpression expr;
    expr = nav.Compile("/NewDataSet/Table1/Database");
    XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);

    try
    {
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            XPathNavigator nav2 = iterator.Current.Clone();              
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
    }
}
```

this will get me all the values from `Database` tags and i cant figure it out how to give those values to `datagridviewtextbox` to show in my `datagridview`. Can anyone help me with this? (P.S. sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
var tables = root.Descendants("Table1")
                 .Select(t => new
                 {
                     Server = t.Element("Server").Value,
                     Database = t.Element("Database").Value
                 });

foreach(var table in tables)
    grid.Rows.Add(new object[] { table.Server, table.Database });
```